# $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{x_n+y_n}$ is the maximum of the sequences' nth root limits

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $x_n $ and $y_n$ be two sequences of positive real numbers then  $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{x_n+y_n}=  \max\left\{\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{x_n} \hspace{1 mm} ; \lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{y_n} \right\}  $

I showed the result if both $x_n $ and $y_n$ converge to different limits but I don't know what to do in case they are equal(the limits). **EDIT:**

let $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{x_n}=l$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{y_n}=l'$ and $l>l'$

we have $|\sqrt[n]{x_n}-l|<\epsilon$ and  $|\sqrt[n]{y_n}-l'|<\epsilon$ take $\epsilon=\displaystyle\frac{l-l'}{2}$ then $l-\displaystyle\frac{l-l'}{2}<\sqrt[n]{x_n}$
$\implies \left(\displaystyle\frac{l+l'}{2}\right)^n<x_n$ we also have $\sqrt[n]{y_n}<l'+\displaystyle\frac{l-l'}{2}$ then ${y_n}<\left(\displaystyle\frac{l+l'}{2}\right)^n$ hence $x_n>y_n$ then $\sqrt[n]x_n <\sqrt[n]{x_n+y_n}< \sqrt[n]{2x_n}$,hence by the squeeze theorem $\sqrt[n]{x_n+y_n}=l$

But what if $l=l'$

Comment: That's odd. Do you mind showing what you did assuming the limits are different?

Comment: @gitgud I added the details

Comment: @user10444: My argument had a hole in it.  I'm working on fixing it now.

Comment: In your argument you didn't prove anything about $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{x_n+y_n}$.

Comment: @eckhard Javaman had already written the method I'll edit it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{x_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{y_n}=L\,$$  then:

$$\sqrt[n]{x_n+y_n}=\sqrt[n]{x_n}\;\sqrt[n]{1+\left(\frac{y_n}{x_n}\right)}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} L\cdot 1=L$$

since by the squeeze theorem

$$1\leftarrow1\leq\sqrt[n]{1+\left(\frac{y_n}{x_n}\right)}\leq\sqrt[n] 3\rightarrow 1$$

Comment: Why is $\sqrt[n]{1+\left(\frac{y_n}{x_n}\right)}\leq\sqrt[n] 3$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio: Nice answer.  I was trying to use that $x - y \approx 0$ rather than $x_n/ y_n \approx 1$, and it seems that the latter is more useful here.  I won't bother adding my (botched) answer back as your answer is much neater.

Comment: Because $\,\frac{y_n}{x_n}\to 1\,$ so that $\,1+\frac{y_n}{x_n}\leq 3\,$ from some index $\,n\,$ on. Note that some refinment must be done if the common limit of both square-n sequences is zero.

Comment: You should add it anyway, @JavaMan: people can learn from this and from that.